# What OBDII protocol does a 2014 Mitsubishi Outlander use?

Tags: obd-ii, mitsubishi

I was trying to help out a friend with an intermittent stalling issue, but the OBD Fusion app could not connect to it via my ELM327 Wi-Fi adapter.

The protocol setting was set to "Automatic", which I believe makes it try the following list of protocols:

- SAE J1850 PWM (41.6 Kbaud)
- SAE J1850 VPW (10.4 Kbaud)
- ISO 9141-2 (5 baud init, 10.4 Kbaud)
- ISO 14320-4 KWP (5 baud init, 10.4 Kbaud)
- ISO 14320-4 KWP (fast init, 10.4 Kbaud)
- ISO 15765-4 CAN (11 bit ID, 500 Kbaud)
- ISO 15765-4 CAN (29 bit ID, 500 Kbaud)
- ISO 15765-4 CAN (11 bit ID, 250 Kbaud)
- ISO 15765-4 CAN (29 bit ID, 250 Kbaud)
- SAE J1939 CAN (29 bit ID, 250 Kbaud)
- USER1 CAN (11 bit ID, 125 Kbaud)
- USER2 CAN (11 bit ID, 50 Kbaud)

So what protocol works with the [2014 Mitsubishi Outlander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_Outlander)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this is the gas and not the hybrid.

Engine = 2.0

Year = 2014

Fuel = Gas

Protocol = CAN 11Bit, 500 baud

Mode 1 = BE3FA813 9017A001 FE108040

Mode 2 = 7E3F8003 00162001 7E108040

[Here's the link](http://www.outilsobdfacile.com/vehicle-list-compatible-obd2/mitsubishi) where I retrieved the info.

Based upon the link it looks like you would be connecting with

- ISO 15765-4 CAN (11 bit ID, 500 Kbaud)

Comment: What's puzzling me is why the app wasn't able to detect it in "Auto" mode. It is in the list of available protocols after all

Comment: @Zaid i see this sometimes on generic obd2 code readers no real explanation as to why though.

Comment: Did it work when you set the protocol?

Comment: I can't remember if I cycled through all the options one by one. What I know is that I tried several protocols and none of them worked. I'll have to wait till I see my friend again to confirm it