# Fuel Trim Readings

Tags: fuel-system, corolla, p0171, trim, lean

I have a 2002 Toyota Corolla (1ZZ-FE engine) and I am trying to understand the fuel trim values I am getting in real driving conditions from my scan tool. I have P0171 code (lean condition) that comes on and off. I posted earlier about this, but I fixed a lot of things in the meantime. I was hoping someone could take a look at the screenshot attached and tell me if these values look off or not.

- STFT mostly remain between -5% - 5% which I think is great.
- LTFT, however, ranges from 12 to 25% These values look high to me, is that right?

I appreciate any insights!

[image: ST and LT fuel trims]

Comment: Yes, 25% is too high.

Comment: Fuel trim high at low rpm and better at higher engine speed.  The first thing I look for is a vacuum leak.

Answer (score 2):

@Fred Wilson's comment is right on the money, high, positive long term fuel trims at idle that reduce at higher engine speeds indicate the presence of higher-than-normal unmetered air.

The fact that it's unmetered indicates that you need to look for something after the MAF/MAP sensor.

Things to check include:

- Unplugged/damaged hoses (e.g. EGR, PCV)
- Cracks in the intake manifold
- Leaky intake manifold gaskets
- Leaky brake booster vacuum line

Fuel management picks up the presence of excess air at exhaust via the O2/lambda sensors and adjusts for it by keeping the fuel injectors open for longer.

This question lists some possible methods to discover the leak source(s):

[How can I detect vacuum leaks without access to a smoke machine?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/29004/675)

All the best.

Comment: Nice explanation of your "diagnostic thinking" and troubleshooting process.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and recommendations, I will keep investigation following these directions. Much appreciated